# Conjugate cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Prove the following in $S_n$:

Let $\alpha = (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_s)$ be a cycle and let $\pi$ be a permutation in $S_n$. Then $\pi\alpha\pi^{-1}$ is the cycle $(\pi(a_1),\ldots,\pi(a_s)).$

---

I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Let $\sigma=\pi\alpha\pi^{-1}$. Calculate
$\sigma(\pi(a_k))$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate that.

Comment: If $a_k$ is in the support of $\alpha$ then $$\sigma(\pi(a_k))=\pi\alpha\pi^{-1}(\pi(a_k))=\pi\alpha(a_k)=\pi(a_{k+1})$$ and the case $a_k=a_s$ is obvious. Now what happens if $a_k$ isn't in the support of $\alpha$?